# Cisco ASA Redirect all traffic from specific outside hosts to specific inside host

Tags: networking, cisco, nat, cisco-asa

I've got a new PBX that I've setup and i will be using a 3rd party sip provider, they've gone ahead and given me an outside number an now i need to allow traffic from 3 different hosts to be able to access a range of ports on the pbx.

I'm assuming this is something i could do with a static rule but every time i attempt to add a second host it'll state the rule already exists or conflicts.

I've already setup the ACL's to allow the traffic, it's all a matter of routing traffic from 3 specific outside addresses to a server on my inside interface.

The ASA is a 5505 and runs 8.4 currently.

Show run stat.

```
davenport# show run static
static (inside,outside) tcp interface 2001 192.168.100.150 2001 netmask 255.255.255.255
static (inside,outside) tcp interface ssh 192.168.100.150 ssh netmask 255.255.255.255
static (inside,outside) tcp interface www Safety2008 8040 netmask 255.255.255.255
static (inside,outside) tcp interface 8041 Safety2008 8041 netmask 255.255.255.255
```

Comment: What does `show run static` show now? (You might want to anonymize the IPs)

Comment: Can you post some of the config?

Comment: @ChrisS added to the main post.

Comment: Is there possibly a way to forward a udp range? that seems like the best solution to me, I can figure out how to forward individual ports but not a range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Answer to this was to simply create a NAT Rule that forwarded all traffic to my pbx from the outside, ACL would block any unwanted traffic, then any other services i provide on the outside simply have a static rule that point to them for example web services.